# Messages disappearing from message queue

Tags: msmq, rebus

In our software we use the Rebus service bus in combination with Microsoft Message Queueing to do various actions. Since some time there are multiple cases where a message is sent to the queue but somehow the message doesn't get picked up by the handler and the message is removed from the queue (or it has never arrived). We can't find the message on the error queue or the dead letter queue. It is lost in space somewhere and we have no idea what happened.

We have enabled the Journal on the queue and for messages that fails we see that the Current Abort Count is set to 3, where messages that are processed succesfully have a Current Abort Count of 1. That correspondents with our rebus configuration (see below), however we have no idea why they are aborted or why some of the messages are failing. There is nothing to be found in the eventlog as well.

This is our current rebus configuration:

```
Configure.With(_adapter).Transport(t => t.UseMsmq(_rpAppBusAddress))
                 .Options(o =>
                 {
                     o.EnableEncryption(_rebusEncryptionKey);
                     o.SimpleRetryStrategy(maxDeliveryAttempts:3);
                     o.EnableDataBus().StoreInSqlServer(rebusConnectionString, attachmentDbTableName);
                 }).Routing(SetRouting())
                 .Start();
```

Anyone have any idea why the messages are disappearing? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: We disabled the limit on storage in MSMQ as well, but that didn't help as well.

Comment: When you say you've checked the dead-letter queue, do you mean Rebus' error queue? Or do you mean MSMQ's "Transactional dead-letter messages" queue?

Comment: We've checked both the rebus error queue as the transactional dead letter queue

Comment: Could you, somehow, have something else that consumes message from the same queue name as specified by `_rpAppBusAddress`?

Comment: The DLQ will only contain messages if negative journaling is enabled on the message.

Comment: @mookid8000 We've checked all applications. There is no other process that consumes the messages from the bus.

Comment: @JohnBreakwell negative journilang is enabled by default by rebus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We figured out why the messages were disappearing. The application didn't have the permissions to put messages on the error queue (shame on us).

Comment: ok.... but did the messages actually disappear? or did they just become invisible, because they were received and then rolled back at some point?

To my knowledge, Rebus cannot lose messages. If the forward-to-error-queue action fails, then the incoming message's `MessageQueueTransaction` will not be committed, thus returning the received message to the input queue

Comment: As far as i could tell the messages disappeared. We found no other trace of the messages on any of the queues in msmq. We do however use an older version of rebus (3.1.5).

Comment: That should not make a difference. Rebus has had a strictly ordered sequence of its operations since always, which dictates that it 1) tries to handle the incoming message, and if that doesn't fail, it 2) tries to send all outgoing messages, and if that doesn't fail it 3) ACKs the incoming message. If something fails along the way, it will NACK the incoming message, effectively making it visible in the queue again..... please let me know if I should help you investigate this further :)

Comment: Well, we solved the problem for now, so no need for an extensive investigation. I do find it interesting in what happened that we couldn't see the messages anywhere in MSMQ. Could it be that it's caused by the fact that the application that puts the message on the queue is the same as the application that processes the message? You would get in a neverending loop of trying to process the message and failing to put it on the error queue.